# Balanced large powers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am looking for large powers that have an equal amount of  digits in some bases.

With a computer search, I have found $2^{17574}$ [balanced](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BCount%5BIntegerDigits%5B2%5E17574%2C3%5D%2Ck%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C2%7D%5D) in base $3$ ( $3696$ digits $k$, $0\le k \le 2$) and $3^{5642}$ [balanced](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Table%5BCount%5BIntegerDigits%5B3%5E5642%2C4%5D%2Ck%5D%2C%7Bk%2C0%2C3%7D%5D) in base $4$, ($1181$ digits $k$, $0\le k\le 3$). I could not find any other powers in larger bases.  Base $10$ would be really surprising. Wonder if anybody could find some larger examples.

Any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Are large perfect squares also allowed ?

Comment: @Peter: They should get praise, yes!  Perhaps base $10$?

Comment: Probably not what you search since you want large powers , but for $10$ digits in base $10$ , there are $87$ solutions , one of which is $9814072356$. In this case , there are only perfect squares. I just try to find a random example with $20$ digits.

Comment: $$10012495377283485696$$ is a perfect square with each digit occuring exactly twice in base $10$.

Comment: What about $$8083478570123877^5$$ ? Large enough ?

Comment: @Peter: Impressive!!  Did it come up with an educated random search?

Comment: In fact, I created random numbers and raised them to the $5$ th power. This turned out to give quick results (even still for a $100$ digit power). However , it will be difficult to find examples with a small base , say $27$. Clear is that the base must be divisible by $3$ because the desired numbers must all be divisible by $9$.

Comment: @Peter: Nice! ... simple and clever;  could a $3^n$ ever work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150739/discussion-between-orangeskid-and-peter).